# How to programmatically create SimpleDraweeViews using Fresco and Android

Tags: android, fresco

I am trying to get 10 images from the server and programmatically create fresco draweeViews and put them into scrollable view.

What I have tried so far

```
 private LinearLayout linearLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    Fresco.initialize(this);
    getImages("1");

} 
public void getImages(String size) {

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        SimpleDraweeView image = new SimpleDraweeView(this);
        image.setLayoutParams(lp);
        // Adds the view to the layout
        linearLayout.addView(image);

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://desolate-beach-17272.herokuapp.com/downloadFile/" + size + "mb" + i + ".jpg");
        image.setImageURI(uri);
    }
}
```

This approached worked with picasso and glide but I couldn't make it work with fresco. Can somone help me with that?

By the way, the server is up and running so you can test it if you want

Answer (score 2):

As the documentation states :

SimpleDraweeView does not support wrap_content for layout_width or layout_height attributes.

So I modified linearLayout parameters and I set min-width for the view. Now it works like a charm

```
 public void getImages(String size) {

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        SimpleDraweeView draweeView = new SimpleDraweeView(this);
        draweeView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        draweeView.setMinimumWidth(150);
        draweeView.setMinimumHeight(1500);
        // Adds the view to the layout
        linearLayout.addView(draweeView);

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://desolate-beach-17272.herokuapp.com/downloadFile/" + size + "mb" + i + ".jpg");

        draweeView.setImageURI(uri);


    }
}
```